# Separators gone and spacing messed up after updating to Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, button, borders

I updated to Ubuntu 16.10 and now there are no button borders; when I hover over buttons, they don't turn blue; and the spacing between tabs in applications like System Settings is messed up too.

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

I've already tried restarting Unity and Compiz.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **System Settings -> Appearance** section to select one of the default themes that comes with Ubuntu (Adwaita or Ambiance for example). If you can't select a theme there because of the missing space and funky UI, try using a tool like `gnome-tweak-tool` instead.

When you upgraded to 16.10 the theme you were using may not have been compatible and the system did not automatically fall back to a theme that works.

I had the same problem you describe and this resolved it for me.